# How to disable Nuxt 3 static generate 200.html and 404.html and _payload.json?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I've noticed that when using Nuxt 3 static generate `nuxt generate`, nuxt automatically generate `200.html`, `404.html`, `_payload.json`.

How can I disable those? I don't want these files because I only have one simple page.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question was asked here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/18831

---

As far as I know, those are required pages to have as a fallback when accessing the server hosting your app.

People may type some `mycoolwebsite.com/about` while it's `mycoolwebsite.com/me` and then face a 500 or some weird error, which will be pretty bad in terms of SEO and also quite confusing to the end user.

The `200.html` is here for the same purpose: route/forward a given request/user agent to your JS payload.   I actually had some issues with that one when it was not given to me (I needed to do some URL rewrites etc...).
TLDR: keep it, thank me later.

For the `payload.json`, isn't it some hydration/prefetching thing?
You either need it or it will not be big anyway in terms of bundle size.

---

If you really want to get rid of those, rather than trying to dig into some deep settings (that may not even be there), I recommend having a `generate` script with `nuxt generate && rm 200.html 404.html` part in it, simple and efficient.
Use it at your own risk tho.

PS: Nuxt is coming with defaults and those have some good reason to be there.

Comment: sometimes I just want a static rendered webpage, fallback route I can use other tools to manage (eg. php server route)
Too bad nuxt 3 doesn't have this option to disable

Comment: @Joseph Nuxt is aimed to help you get from A to B faster, you can always opt out of it with a few lines of bash scripting and run your own thing. Nuxt does that to help you ship the code to as many places as possible most of the time for free. PHP fallback is not the main priority, so there is no point in bloating the framework with too much complexity I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the generation of these files:

1. You can create a "nuxt.config.js" file in the root directory of your Nuxt project if it doesn't already exist.
2. Inside the "nuxt.config.js" file, you can adjust the "generate" configuration. Specifically, you should include a "fallback" property to customize how 404 pages are handled, and you can omit the "payload" property to prevent the generation of the "_payload.json" file.

Comment: it doesn't work with nuxt 3